# How to use simple deform to bend geometry in a circle?

Tags: modifiers

I feel like something is just going way over my head here and I'm missing something really trivial. I'm doing a Grant Abbit well tutorial. I created a set of cubes along the x axis to use as the rocks for the well. I added a simple deform modifier. If I set it to bend at the z axis at 45 degrees, it makes a weird fan shape. I did also try making the origin set to an empty and that just swings the fan around.

File download: https://pasteall.org/blend/e826991d5a5e4e3b8f94e0ec92ff333f

[image: Fan Shape]

[image: Settings]

Comment: maybe you rotated it in Object mode? Try to apply your object rotation...

Comment: Ok I just tried appplying all transforms and the same thing happens

Comment: So I just tried using the simple deform on an object that is by itself and not joined by other objects and it acts the way I would expect it to. So something about have mutiple joined objects is screwing it up

Comment: mmh maybe share your file so that we can understand what's happening though...

Comment: Sorry I'm also trying to figure that out. I've always used blend exchange, but it hasn't been working for me recently. My filesize is less than a mb. Do you know any other way I can upload it?

Comment: try this one: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: This work?
https://pasteall.org/blend/e826991d5a5e4e3b8f94e0ec92ff333f

Comment: 'Simple' Deform scrambles my head unless I target it on an axis-arrows Empty for its origin/orientation, and rotate/move the Empty. I think that makes it easier to try orientations out, and see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object is currently aligned with the Y axis, it needs to be aligned with X axis, so rotate it 90°, apply the rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Agh once I rotated it onto the x axis and applied the transforms it worked. That's kind of an important point that should be included in tutorials. Thanks!